# Is this the correct way for me to create javascript namespaces with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I recently asked a question but couldn't really understand the answer. Here's what I have been able to understand. Can someone please verify if this is the correct way to go about doing something similar to C# where I have namespaces? Note that below are three files and they all have references to each other but these are not show here:

```
/Admin/dialog/start.ts
module Admin.dialog {
    export function x() { };
    Admin.grid.y(); // executes the function inside of file2.ts
}

/Admin/dialog/file1.ts
module Admin.dialog {
    export function y() { };
}

/Admin/grid/file2.ts   
module Admin.grid {
    export function y() { };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my suggested structure:

*./Admin/Dialog.ts*

```
module Admin {
    export class Dialog {
        x() {
            this.y();
        }

        y() {

        }
    }
}
```

*./Admin/Grid.ts*

```
module Admin {
    export class Grid {
        y() {
        }
    }
}
```

You can then use these modules like this:

```
///<reference path="./Admin/Dialog.ts" />
///<reference path="./Admin/Grid.ts" />

var dialog = new Admin.Dialog();
dialog.x();

var grid = new Admin.Grid();
grid.y();
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The only one thing I am not sure of is I have many functions in the directory /Admin/Dialog/ directory and each of these functions are in their own file. For example x.ts and y.ts and z.ts for the functions x(), y() and z().  Given this scenario how would you suggest I use modules?

Comment: I would move all of those functions into the "Dialog" class in the "Admin" module as they are related and are likely to change for the same reason.